# What is the difference between a simple function and a function with this keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, modular-design

I have the following code-

```
var x=function(){
  alert("hello");
}
var z=x;
z();// it works nicely
```

Now say I modified the code a bit-

```
 var x=function(){
   this.show=function(){
   alert("hello");
   }
 }
 var z=x;// It doesn't work unless I write var z=new x(); 
 z.show();
```

I am wondering what difference 'this' keyword is creating between this two function and why I need to use an extra new keyword in the second case.

Comment: z.show doesn't work with `z = x` because z.show doesn't exist until the function is called. creating a `new x()` will in effect start the function and store it as z. Inside of x you've told the program that `this.show` will be a function. calling `z.show` without newing it up would be like calling a static function on a class, which i'm pretty sure JS doesn't have

Comment: You could return an object from `x` function call which has property `"show"`